# Mark contents in iframe from same origin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having troubles to get mark.js working  with contents in iframe from same origin.
At the moment of cration of the new Mark instance is present the iframe content but the search function does not mark its contents. Here is the plunker where is reproduced my issue. I believe to being missing something and need your help. Thanks in advance!

visit: https://plnkr.co/edit/kbO60qEPLvZpH9BXhrZd

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mark.js/8.6.0/mark.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/superhero/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 15px;
        }

        div.search span,
        div.search input[name="keyword"] {
            display: block;
        }

        div.search input[name="keyword"] {
            margin-top: 4px;
        }

        div.panel {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        div.panel .panel-body p:last-child {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        mark {
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>


    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="search row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body context">
            <p>
               Dummy text not in iframe: Lorem ipsum...
            </p>
__________________________________

            <iframe style="width:100%;height: 600px;background-color: white;" src="1.html"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var options = {
                "separateWordSearch": false,
                "diacritics": false,
                "acrossElements": true,
                "iframes": true,
                //"iframesTimeout": 5000,
                "debug": true,
            };


            var keywordInput = document.querySelector("input[name='keyword']");

            function performMark() {

            var markInstance = new Mark(document.querySelector(".context"));

                var keyword = keywordInput.value;

                markInstance.unmark({
                    done: function () {
                        markInstance.mark(keyword, options);
                    }
                });
            };

            keywordInput.addEventListener("input", performMark);

        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix was discussed in the following issue:
https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/issues/137

Comment: yes I know, I opened the issue request on gitHub :D Thanks